# MS Access - Amount of recurrence calls within specific time frame

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access DB in which I have a history of call data.

I would like to update a column which indicates, if this is a call from somebody, who tried to contact us already a specific time ago, let's say 180 minutes ago.

The column in which the number of the caller is, is called "caller" and column in which the arrival time of the call stands is labeld as "Call_Start"

In Excel I found a solution, however I have no clue how to transponse this solution into access.

Thank you for your feedback!

markus

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hey Gordon,
 here is a sample.
the "1"  I entered manually. But that should be the result I would like to achieve by a sql query.
https://imgur.com/a/9kksXYj

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference in minutes you would use a calculated field in a query something like;

```
TimeDiff: DateDiff("n",[Call_Start],Now())
```

The full syntax for DateDiff is here https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/datediff-function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f

Comment: Hey Minty, thank you for your answer. Getting the time difference is not the issue. The thing is, that per caller id if need to check, if there was a call some time ago (e.g. 60 Minutes) from the same caller id and if so, I want that new call marked as a recurrent caller